# Migrate non-redundant data to larger disk on Synology NAS

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, synology, data-migration

I have a Synology DS213j using two disks I had to spare, 2TB and 1.5TB. These are nearly full so I plan to replace them. To put all data onto the new disks I just wanted to connect the old disks to my desktop computer and copy the files. But now I read that this might not be possible because of the raid, even though I didn't really use one. The disks are in a Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR), but without any data protection so I can use the full space as you can see on the screenshot.

[image: Volumes Screenshot]

Also all my shared folders are explicitly on a single volume as you can see here

[image: Shared Folders Screenshot]

So as far as I know SHR just causes the volumes to appear as a single logical unit in this case but does not spread any data. Am I right about this? Can I just connect the old disks to my computer and copy the data or does SHR prevent this simple approach? If so, how else could I do it? To say upfront: I don't have 3.5TB of free storage to store the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I grasp [this Synology guide](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/faq/579) correctly, Synology Hybrid RAID is just a fancy name for Linux MDRAID coupled with Linux LVM. The filesystem is already visible on your screenshots: ext4. It’s available on virtually any maintained distributions.

The basic steps are these:

1. Connect all drives to your PC
2. Use some suitable Linux distribution (like Ubuntu), either installed or booted from a Live CD/USB
3. Install the `mdadm` and `lvm2` packages (name may vary)
4. Run `mdadm -As && vgchange -ay` to start MDRAID and scan for LVM volumes

   - If, and only if, it doesn’t work with `mdadm -As`, use `mdadm -Asf` to import even damaged arrays
5. Access data either via your distributions auto-mounting mechanism or by manually mounting them

   - You can find volume names with `lvs`, they are typically located at `/dev/<vg name>/<lv name>`.

These steps should work for any kind of SHR configuration.